# How to use a list from a function into another function

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, class

I'm making a GUI program that there are two buttons. When I click the first button, I want to generating a random code. When I click the second button, I want to see a list of the codes that generated from the first button. (For now, just to print the codes-list, into the 'Run' window.) My script is the following:

```
class Ui_Main_Window(object):

    # For the first button:
    def Code_maker(self):
        import random
        Codes_list = []
        chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!$%^&*`#/\?[]{}-_~"
        for x in range(1):
            password = ""
            for y in range(0, 10):
                password_char = random.choice(chars)
                password += password_char
            print(password)
            Codes_list.append(password)

    # For the second button:
    def show_list(self):
             print (Codes_list)

    # To connect the actions with the buttons:
    def setupUi(self, Main_Window):
        # After some code...
        self.Button_New_code.clicked.connect(self.Code_maker)
        # After some code...
        self.Button_Show_list.clicked.connect(self.show_list)
# The continuation of the program...
```

My problem is that when I click the first button, the code genarating successfully and it printing into the 'Run' window. But when I click the second button the program crashes and after some seconds, it closes. I get this error:

```
> Unresolved reference 'Codes_list'.
```

*(I use Pycharm and the error doesn't showing into the 'Run' window, but into the 'Problems' window.)*

I tried to repair it with a global list, but the program works worse. It crashes when I click anything of the two buttons... If I write code with this way, it becomes:

```
class Ui_Main_Window(object):

    Codes_list = []

    # For the first button:
    def Code_maker(self):
        import random
        global Codes_list
        chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!$%^&*`#/\?[]{}-_~"
        for x in range(1):
            password = ""
            for y in range(0, 10):
                password_char = random.choice(chars)
                password += password_char
            print(password)
            Codes_list.append(password)

    # For the second button:
    def show_list(self):
             print (Codes_list)

    # To connect the actions with the buttons:
    def setupUi(self, Main_Window):
        # After some code...
        self.Button_New_code.clicked.connect(self.Code_maker)
        # After some code...
        self.Button_Show_list.clicked.connect(self.show_list)
```

I searched about my problem in Google, but I tried so many things, that I don't remember what I tried. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I have added comments on the lines I have added or modified for your reference. Can you please check?

```
class Ui_Main_Window(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # added the constructor to attach the list with the object itself
        self.Codes_list = []  #this will contain the numbers

    # For the first button:
    def Code_maker(self):
        import random
        #Codes_list = []  # Removed
        chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!$%^&*`#/\?[]{}-_~"
        for x in range(1):
            password = ""
            for y in range(0, 10):
                password_char = random.choice(chars)
                password += password_char
            print(password)
            self.Codes_list.append(password)  # modified to update the object attribute

    # For the second button:
    def show_list(self):
             print (self.Codes_list)  # modified to access the object attribute

    # To connect the actions with the buttons:
    def setupUi(self, Main_Window):
        # After some code...
        self.Button_New_code.clicked.connect(self.Code_maker)
        # After some code...
        self.Button_Show_list.clicked.connect(self.show_list)
    # The continuation of the program...
```